# How to duplicate rows of existing table and change value of one column based on a simple condition

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R, and I would appreciate help from experts for this problem.
I have Products table like this:

Table1 : Existing Products

```
ProductId Width  Thickness
CM72      4.2     12
CM73      1.2     76
CM84      3.5     32
CM93      2.1     31
```

Table2 : New Products

```
ProductId    
CG72
CG93
```

I want to append the ProductId of the NewProducts table to the existing Products table. And I want to copy the Width and Thickness and Length from the similar numbered existing product. CM72 -> is the match for CG72. CM93 -> match for CG93.

Final table should look like this:

```
ProductId Width  Thickness
CM72      4.2     12
CM73      1.2     76
CM84      3.5     32
CM93      2.1     31
CG72      4.2     12
CG93      2.1     31
```

Is there an effective way to do this in R? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We replace the 'G' with 'M' in the 'ProductId' of second dataset ('df2') using `sub`, get the index of row in 'df1' by `match`ing with 'ProductId', subset the 2nd and 3rd column with only the rows based on the `match` ids, `cbind` with the second dataset 'df2' and then `rbind` with the 'df1'

```
dfN <- rbind(df1,  cbind(df2, df1[match(sub("G", "M", df2$ProductId), df1$ProductId), 2:3]))
row.names(dfN) <- NULL
dfN
#  ProductId Width Thickness
#1      CM72   4.2        12
#2      CM73   1.2        76
#3      CM84   3.5        32
#4      CM93   2.1        31
#5      CG72   4.2        12
#6      CG93   2.1        31
```

---

Or another option is with `data.table`, We get the datasets in a `list`, `rbind`, grouped by the substring of 'ProductId', loop through the other columns, get the non-NA elements and assign (`:=`) it to the columns

```
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)[, (2:3) := 
 lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), .(grp = sub("G", "M", ProductId))][]
#    ProductId Width Thickness
#1:      CM72   4.2        12
#2:      CM73   1.2        76
#3:      CM84   3.5        32
#4:      CM93   2.1        31
#5:      CG72   4.2        12
#6:      CG93   2.1        31
```

---

A corresponding `tidyverse` approach would be

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
     group_by(grp =  sub("G", "M", ProductId)) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(Width:Thickness), funs(.[!is.na(.)])) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     select(-grp)
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ProductId = c("CM72", "CM73", "CM84", "CM93"), 
Width = c(4.2, 1.2, 3.5, 2.1), Thickness = c(12L, 76L, 32L, 
31L)), .Names = c("ProductId", "Width", "Thickness"),
 class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ProductId = c("CG72", "CG93")),
.Names = "ProductId", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun! I will try this out